How defensible is it in 21st century to attribute "Sinim" in Isa 49:12 to China?
A Daily Mail article embellishing news of an archeological find of a Chinese bowl fragment dated between 1520 to 1570 says:

Fruitful, peaceful contact between Jewish and Chinese traders may, in fact, date as far back as the Old Testament, with a passage in the Book of Isaiah (49:12) that makes reference [to] visitors using the Hebrew terms for China, 'Sin' and 'Sinim.'

Responding to a comment, of course an article from a "daily middle-market tabloid newspaper published in London" is not sufficient in itself to occasion a question in BH.SE, but this triggers my memory of seeing this interpretation somewhere else, which I also found in a more enlightened source such as the 1938 International Standard Bible Encyclopedia (dated, but still popular among Evangelicals) which says the following in its entry of "Sinim, Land Of":

... Many scholars have favored identification with China, the classical Sinae. It seems improbable that Jews had already found their way to China; but from very early times trade relations were established with the Far East by way of Arabia and the Persian Gulf; and the name may have been used by the prophet simply as suggesting extreme remoteness. ... While no certain decision is possible, probability points to the East, and China cannot be quite ruled out ...

Has there been any recent (preferably 21st century) commentaries or scholarly journal articles that make a plausible case that the author of Isa 49:12 was indeed thinking of China?
Here's Isa 49:12 (CSB):

See, these will come from far away,
from the north and from the west,[a]
and from the land of Sinim.[b][c]

b. DSS read of the Syenites
c. Perhaps modern Aswan in southern Egypt


Really? How defensible is it to attribute anything to a Dailymail article when your entire audience either sees your mistake, or has no idea what you mean, yet hope to be taken seriously about Biblical Hermeneutics?
I strongly suggest you scrap that Question and replace with a new one that speaks not of your current mistake, but of the Daily Mail.
Would you rather be seen as clear about such a trivial query in every-day modern English, or unclear about vital details of ancient translations?
Your choice, and what matters to you?

@RobbieGoodwin Ah, we meet again.  OK, OK.  I was being lazy in citing a Dailymail  tabloid article.  But still, I knew from the beginning that there is a good underlying question, making it NOT worthy to be scrapped as you dismissively suggested, but only needs a better and plausible interpretive option that it was referring to China, which I provided in my edited question.  So rather than just commenting on the state of my question, why don't you answer the question yourself?  If not, Merry Christmas, and peace be with you.

So, rather than just expressing offence at a Comment your Question pretty-much invited by basing itself on one word published in a popular newspaper whose name you mangled, why not consider the Answers here?

Can you say how this 21st century changes anything?

@RobbieGoodwin "Can you say how this 21st century changes anything?"  Emphatically YES!  Biblical interpretation in the past 30-40 years has changed so much due to research in 3 areas: Ancient Near East, Second Temple Judaism, and 20th century literary criticism (that much expands the Reader's World).  So in my personal study as well as more informed scholarly theological books, I notice a definite preference to interpretation from later decades which in some case overturned ancient ones.

@RobbieGoodwin "whose name you mangled"  OK, I corrected the OP to the official spelling just to make you happy.   "why not consider the Answers here"  I accepted DanFefferman's answer but withdrew it for lack of citations. If I want to, I can write my own answer but I prefer to dedicate my time to other pursuit, especially since I admit that although this Q is on topic and well-formed enough, it is NOT a great question (I would be surprised if in the next 10 years it has 10 votes); rather it's like satisfying an itch.

Good for you and if your ability to write your own Answer mattered here, why did you not simply write that, rather than taking people's  time with what you now seem to describe as a pointless Question?

Not accurate. Although some scholars still insist that "China" is correct, most contemporary interpreters understand this to refer to the place know today as Aswan, which at the time was located at the first cataract of the Nile in southern Egypt. In ancient times the name was written swnw, which explains how a Hebrew writer might call it Sinam or Sinim - the key consonants "s" and "n" being identical. (Most ancient middle eastern languages lacked vowels when in written form.) It later came to be known as Syene and finally Aswan.
Another argument in favor of Aswan rather than China is that China did not officially open trade with the West in 130 B.C., when the Silk Road routes were established. This does not entirely rule out the possibility that Isaiah would be inspired to write about China, but it is more likely that he would refer to the "known world" rather than the "future known world."

Many modern traslators identify Sinam with ancient Seyene (or swnw), today known as Aswan.

This is a digression, but...I thought the reason for the Tetragrammaton being spelled YHWH omitting vowels was to avoid spelling it all out.  Was ancient Hebrew not one of the "Most ancient middle eastern languages" that lacked vowels?  Just trying to square what I think I know, with what you've just said.

Re: "Most ancient middle eastern languages lacked vowels": The languages certainly had vowels! I guess you're thinking of how their writing systems didn't always indicate those vowels (much like how English spelling doesn't indicate which syllable in a word is stressed); but I don't see how that's relevant here. If an Israelite asked an Egyptian traveler where he was from, even if both of them magically happened to know hieroglyphics, the traveler would surely just reply aloud, rather than asking for writing materials and leaving the Israelite to guess at the pronunciation.

Sorry to withdraw "accepted" status from your answer, as I want to make the question more useful by asking for 21st century commentary / scholarly journal article to make a judgment on the referent.

Here are three comments from three respected lexicons:

Brown-Driver-Briggs (1906)

סִינִים adjective, of a people plural = substantive; ׳אֶרֶץ ס Isaiah 49:12, identification with Chinese by Thes948-950 De CheComm. and others; but see see RichthofenChina i. 436 f., 504, reviewed by YuleAcad. xiii. 339; Di Du; T. de LacouperieBOR i. 45 ff., 183 ff., who thinks of Šina, at foot of Hindu Kush, but unlikely; read probably סְוֵנִים (or סְוָנִים), so CheIntr. Is. 275, and Hpt., compare already JDMich.


Strong's Lexicon (1890)

The exact identification of "Sinim" is uncertain, and various interpretations have been proposed. Some scholars suggest it refers to a region in the southern part of Egypt, while others propose it could be linked to regions in Asia, possibly China, due to phonetic similarities. In the ancient world, the term might have been used to denote a distant and exotic location, emphasizing the universality of God's promise to gather His people from all corners of the earth.


Complete Word Study Dictionary (Baker & Carpenter, 2003)

A masculine proper noun designating the Sinim people, perhaps from southern China (KJV, NKJV, Isa 49:12)



I note that the OP's link to an archeological find might lend weight to the suggested identification of "Sinim" with China, especially as the word has come into English as a demotic adjective of things Chinese.
Commentaries

Ellicott (1870s) favors the interpretation "China" and offers an extensive defense
The Berean Bible notes (2016) use "Aswan" but do not exclude China
The Pulpit commentary (1909) suggests "China" but also suggests "Phoenicia".
The Cambridge Commentary (1979) calls "Sinim", "a hopeless enigma".
Barnes (1830s) enumerates numerous possibilities but does not draw a final conclusion
etc.

Difficulties
As stated above, the great difficulty in translating the Hebrew "sinim" is two-fold:

It is the only time it occurs in the Herew OT
There is no unanimity among ancient transitions: the LXX suggests "Persia" and the Vulgate suggests "land of the south"

Even the context is not all that helpful.  Note my very literal translation of Isa 49:12:

Surely these shall come from afar and Look

these from the north
and [from] the sea (ie, Mediterranean sea)
and these from the land of Sinim


Thus, in this context, "Sinim" could be either "east" as in Persia (the LXX), or "south" as per the vulgate.  Thus, we cannot be sure.
APPENDIX - Other Versions
For completeness, other versions identify "Sinim" people differently:

NIV, BSB, NASB, ISV: Aswan
NLT, CEV: South Egypt
ESV, NHEB, NAB: land of Syrene
LXX: γῆς Περσῶν (land of the Persians)
Latin Vulgate: terra australi (land of the south)


great research, thanks

As quoted here of BDB starts this way:  "סְוֵנִים - adjective, of a people plural Syenites". Syenites is set off in boldface type.

There is also the Sinite(s) descended from Canaan son of Ham according to Genesis 10:17, often thought to be in north Lebanon.

None of the proposed answers has a final 'm'.  I don't know Hebrew, but is -im a plural suffix?

@MikeMaxwell - yes the "sinim" means plural.  The word occurs now where else in the OT.  As explained above, this is highly debated.
